# show average rating in read mode and just total or half value in write mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create star rating where the functionality has to be following:

> In read mode, the stars are shown as per average (should support 100%
>   i.e 5 or 96% i.e 4.6) in write mode, the user can only rate 1, 1.5, 2,
>   2.5 etc not 2.6

The read mode is working as expected but is having problem with write mode.
The problem in write mode is I cannot update the rating with non-decimal value from 1 to 5 and also half value like 1.5, 2.5, 3.5 etc. On hovering how do i decide if my mouse pointer is in the full star or half of star? Can anyone look at this, please?

I have created a sandbox for showing the demo

Here it is

https://codesandbox.io/s/9l6kmnw7vw

The code is as follow

UPDATED CODE

```
// @flow

import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const StyledIcon = styled.i`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: ${props => props.direction && props.direction};
  ${props => props.css && css(...props.css)};
`;

const StyledRating = styled.div`
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 125px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #a2a2a2;
  color: grey;
`;

const TopStyledRating = styled.div`
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  ${props => props.css && css(...props.css)};
  width: ${props => props.width && props.width};
`;

const BottomStyledRating = styled.div`
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
`;

class Rating extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rating: this.props.rating || null,
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      temp_rating: null
    };
  }

  handleMouseover(rating) {
    console.log("rating", rating);
    this.setState(prev => ({
      rating,
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      temp_rating: prev.rating
    }));
  }

  handleMouseout() {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      rating: prev.temp_rating
    }));
  }

  rate(rating) {
    this.setState({
      rating,
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      temp_rating: rating
    });
  }

  calculateWidth = value => {
    const { total } = this.props;
    const { rating } = this.state;
    return Math.floor((rating / total) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
  };

  render() {
    const { disabled, isReadonly } = this.props;
    const { rating } = this.state;
    const topStars = [];
    const bottomStars = [];
    const writableStars = [];
    console.log("rating", rating);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    if (isReadonly) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        topStars.push(<span>★</span>);
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        bottomStars.push(<span>★</span>);
      }
    } else {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let klass = "star_border";
        if (rating >= i && rating !== null) {
          klass = "star";
        }
        writableStars.push(
          <StyledIcon
            direction={i % 2 === 0 ? "ltr" : "rtl"}
            className="material-icons"
            css={this.props.css}
            onMouseOver={() => !disabled && this.handleMouseover(i)}
            onFocus={() => !disabled && this.handleMouseover(i)}
            onClick={() => !disabled && this.rate(i)}
            onMouseOut={() => !disabled && this.handleMouseout()}
            onBlur={() => !disabled && this.handleMouseout()}
          >
            {klass}
          </StyledIcon>
        );
      }
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {isReadonly ? (
          <StyledRating>
            <TopStyledRating
              css={this.props.css}
              width={this.calculateWidth(this.props.rating)}
            >
              {topStars}
            </TopStyledRating>
            <BottomStyledRating>{bottomStars}</BottomStyledRating>
          </StyledRating>
        ) : (
          <React.Fragment>
            {rating}
            {writableStars}
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Rating.defaultProps = {
  css: "",
  disabled: false
};

export default Rating;
```

Now the writable stars is separately done to show the stars status when hovering and clicking but when I am supplying rating as 5 it is filling the third stars instead of 5th.

Comment: So, can you give a bit more detail what your problem is in write mode? I can see the images are kinda jumping around in your sandbox, but describing your problem in more detail (not code), could significantly reduce the code we need to look at :) Is the problem that currently the stars are disappearing because you recalculate the width?

Comment: @Icepickle I have updated my question. My problem is i could not rate because on hovering, i could not decide the full star hover and half star hover so i can update the rating state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current problem seems to be with where your mouse event is set, as you are handling it on the individual stars, they disappear, and trigger a `mouseout` event, causing this constant switch in visibility.

I would rather set the detection of the rating on the outer div, and then track where the mouse is in relation to the div, and set the width of the writable stars according to that.

I tried to make a sample from scratch, that shows how you could handle the changes from the outer div. I am sure the formula I used can be simplified still, but okay, this was just to demonstrate how it can work.

```js
const { Component } = React;

const getRating = x => (parseInt(x / 20) * 20 + (x % 20 >= 13 ? 20 : x % 20 >= 7 ? 10 : 0));

class Rating extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appliedRating: '86%'
    };
    this.setParentElement = this.setParentElement.bind( this );
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind( this );
    this.applyRating = this.applyRating.bind( this );
    this.reset = this.reset.bind( this );
    this.stopReset = this.stopReset.bind( this );
  }
  stopReset() {
    clearTimeout( this.resetTimeout );
  }
  setParentElement(e) {
    this.parentElement = e;
  }
  handleMouseOver(e) {
    this.stopReset();
    if (e.currentTarget !== this.parentElement) {
      return;
    }
    const targetRating = getRating(e.clientX - this.parentElement.offsetLeft);
    if (this.state.setRating !== targetRating) {
      this.setState({
        setRating: targetRating
      });
    }
  }
  applyRating(e) {
    this.setState({
      currentRating: this.state.setRating
    });
  }
  reset(e) {
    this.resetTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.setState( { setRating: null } ), 50 );
  }
  renderStars( width, ...classes  ) {
    return (
      <div 
        onMouseEnter={this.stopReset} 
        className={ ['flex-rating', ...classes].join(' ')} 
        style={{width}}>
        <span onMouseEnter={this.stopReset} className="star">★</span>
        <span onMouseEnter={this.stopReset} className="star">★</span>
        <span onMouseEnter={this.stopReset} className="star">★</span>
        <span onMouseEnter={this.stopReset} className="star">★</span>
        <span onMouseEnter={this.stopReset} className="star">★</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
  renderFixed() {
    return this.renderStars('100%', 'fixed');
  }
  renderReadOnlyRating() {
    const { appliedRating } = this.state;
    return this.renderStars( appliedRating, 'readonly' );
  }
  renderWriteRating() {
    let { setRating, currentRating } = this.state;
    if (setRating === 0) {
      setRating = '0%';
    }
    if (currentRating === undefined) {
      currentRating = '100%';
    }
    return this.renderStars( setRating || currentRating, 'writable' );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div 
          ref={ this.setParentElement }
          className="rating" 
          onMouseMove={ this.handleMouseOver }
          onMouseOut={ this.reset }
          onClick={ this.applyRating }>
          { this.renderFixed() }
          { this.renderReadOnlyRating() }
          { this.renderWriteRating() }
        </div>
        <div>Current rating: { ( ( this.state.currentRating || 0 ) / 20) }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Rating />, document.getElementById('container') );
```

```css
body { margin: 50px; }
.rating {
  font-family: 'Courier new';
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}
.flex-rating {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fixed {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.readonly {
  color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.writable {
  color: blue;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
}
.star {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  max-width: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I have created sandbox from your code. I see you have supplied appliedRating as 86%. It should i think highlight the 4th star as 4.3 but its highlighting all those 5 stars. https://codesandbox.io/s/4qlk4lxvq7

Comment: @milan please don't forget I have 3 stars there, one for all, one for the set ratings and one for the user to write to. The code here is runnable though

Comment: Sorry i still did not get it. Should not it highlight 4th star slightly? because 86% means 4.5 out of 5. regarding the sandbox i created is for understanding your code by tweaking. I appreciate your answer and helping nature.

Comment: @milan Oh, I think I see the problem, nl, that I set the writeable to 5 when there is no user defined setting yet :| If you move over the stars to the first one, you should see that the readonly stars (the grey ones, have till 4 stars filled (partly) ) and the black stars are all the stars which are behind it (so blue is the users current selection, all 5 when none are selected or hovered), grey the ones which are average, black simply shows the full range of stars. The background I added, so you could see how far the selection actually goes :)

Comment: thank you for your time and helping nature. I understand this now i have a challenge to make the size of stars more flexible based on the provided props. Thank you again. I have marked this as solved